# How to calculate the exact value of $\sin{10}$?

Tags: trigonometry

This is what I tried doing.
Yes, $10$ as in $10$ degrees.

I used the formula $\sin{3x} = 3\sin{x} - 4\sin^3{x}$ to get the cubic equation
$x^3-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{1}{8}=0$, where $x$ is $\sin{10}$. When I tried using the cubic formula on it, it prompted the calculation of $\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{-3}-1}{2}}$. Putting that into [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cbrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B-3%7D-1%7D%7B2%7D%7D) tells me that this is equal to $e^{\frac{2}{9}i\pi}$. This leads to me having to calculate $(\sqrt[9]{i})^4$. To calculate the ninth root of $i$, I used the following technique.

$\sqrt[9]{i} = a+b i$
$0 + 1i = (a+b i)^9$
$0 + 1i = a^9-36a^7b^2+126a^5b^4-84a^3b^6+9ab^8+i(9a^8b-84a^6b^3+126a^4b^5-36a^2b^7+b^9)$

This gives me the simultaneous equations:
$a^9-36a^7b^2+126a^5b^4-84a^3b^6+9ab^8 = 0$ and $9a^8b-84a^6b^3+126a^4b^5-36a^2b^7+b^9=1$

Again, I tried using [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%5E9-36a%5E7b%5E2%2B126a%5E5b%5E4-84a%5E3b%5E6%2B9ab%5E8+%3D+0%2C+9a%5E8b-84a%5E6b%5E3%2B126a%5E4b%5E5-36a%5E2b%5E7%2Bb%5E9%3D1) to solve this, but that didn't lead anywhere, since the correct answer had $i$ in another more complicated nested cube root.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: 1. Is $10$ meant as degrees ? 2. I think that an expression exactly calculating $\sin(10°)$ is ugly.

Comment: Observe that $\sin 10^\circ = \text{Im}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{36}})$. This suggests to me that your intermediate answer $e^{\frac{2}{9}i\pi}$ is somehow incorrect.

Comment: Why do you want this?  Closed forms for cubics are generally bad.  [WA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation#:~:text=Actuarial%20notation%20is%20a%20shorthand,interest%20rates%20and%20life%20tables.) can give you the radical form if you really want it.  The one you want is the middle one.

Comment: @lulu Most questions in maths don't have an answer to this question except "just for fun". That's my answer too.

Comment: For those who do not know what WA is : It stands for "Wolfram Alpha" and is a quite powerful mathematical online tool.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins the cube root is just one part of it, not the entire answer

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=8x%5E3-6x%2B1%3D0) satisfies you. The second expression is what you want. Click on "exact form" for the expression.

Comment: @Peter WA destroys quite a bit of beautiful symmetry in those exact forms when it insists for some inexplicable reason on having one of the radicals in a denominator.

Comment: @avighnac I see. In any case you need to be careful asking WA to calculate the result. That expression has up to 6 values (2 for the square root, 3 for the cube root). Do you know which value you need?

Comment: @Peter that expression has imaginary numbers even though the final answer has none; I have an expression with imaginary numbers simpler than that, so that doesn’t satisfy me.

Comment: Then , google "casus irreducibilis" to see that this is impossible here , at least with algebraic methods.

Comment: Even if you use the [cubic formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiYiZDD5o_8AhVqKFkFHQRBBp0QFnoECAwQBg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utah.edu%2F~wortman%2F1060text-tcf.pdf&usg=AOvVaw27PnTQQaGNqrofPtSyPS_P), you will cycle through cube roots of other complex numbers.

Comment: @Peter, sorry if this makes me sound a little foolish, but this just seems incredibly hard to comprehend, surely it can’t be impossible; if one can take the roots of unity then why can one not express a perfectly real number with no imaginary part without complex numbers?!

Comment: It is a proven result that with this approach you cannot avoid non-real numbers here , there is also a geometrical approach, not sure whether this establishes what you want.

Comment: @svighnac Congratulations, you have discovered one of the biggest headaches of renaissance mathematicians. You need complex numbers.

Comment: We can take $\sin$ of $10=15-15/2+15/4-15/8+15/16-...$